# Intercepting tcp/ UDP packets

Tags: security, proxy, intercept

Would like to know is there any proxy available for intercepting tcp/udp traffic.
We have the tcp and udp traffic that cannot be intercepted via any other web debugging proxy. 
Appreciate  if anyone can suggest right solution for the same.

Thanks

Umesh Narayanan

Comment: I feel like "intercept" might be ambiguous.  Are you trying to keep the traffic from propigating, or just see its content?  Or are you literally trying to redirect it like a proxy?

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention `tcp` and `udp` packets, and then later a "debugging proxy", I assume that you would like to make all network traffic go though a device for analysis.

There are such devices. This is usually a firewall, a more sophisticated firewall which embarks packet analysis (enterprise firewalls often have such modules available, Checkpoint comes to mind for instance) or a Intruder Detection/Protection System (IDS/IPS) which analysis traffic to uncover malicious elements.

There are open source firewalls (`iptables` on Linux for instance) and IDSes ([Suricata](https://suricata-ids.org/) for instance) but you will probably quickly hit the encryption wall (data which is encrypted between the client and server)